# Displaying Multiple Arrays in a Table

Tags: php, arrays

I have 5 arrays

```
    $array1 = array('ar1_1','ar1_2','ar1_3','ar1_4');
    $array2 = array('ar2_1','ar2_2','ar2_3','ar2_4','ar2_5');
    $array3 = array('ar3_1','ar3_2','ar3_3','ar3_4','ar3_5','ar3_6');
    $array4 = array('ar4_1','ar4_2','ar4_3','ar4_4');
    $array5 = array('ar5_1','ar5_2','ar5_3');
    $loc = array('AM','IN','US');
```

I want to display it in a manner;

```
<table>
<tr class="d1 vevent">
<td>
<b><abbr class="dtstart" title="' . $array1 . '">' . $array2 . '</abbr></b> <br>' . $array3 . '</td>
<td>
<span class="summary">' . $array4 . ' - ' . $array5 . '</span>
<span class="location">' . $loc . '</span>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Any solution ?

I've tried for loop, foreach loop, zip, array_merge and array_combine but unable to attain desired results.

The code I've tried:

```
echo '<table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
<tbody>
<tr class="toprow">
<td><strong>Date </strong></td>
<td><strong> Details</strong></td>
</tr>';


/*
foreach(array_combine($date, $time) as $time1 => $date1)
{
 @$date1 = split('[()]', $date1);
  echo $time1. $date1[1]. "<br />";
} */




$result = count($match_no);
for($i=0; $i<$result; $i++) {
echo '
<tr class="d1 vevent">
<td>
<b><abbr class="dtstart" title="';
echo trim($date[0]);
echo '">';
echo $date[0]; 
echo '</abbr></b> <br>';

foreach($time as $time1)
{
 @$time1 = split('[()]', $time1);
  echo $time1[1];
}
echo '</td>
<td>
<span class="summary">';
echo $match_no[0];
echo ' - <a href="';
echo '#" class="url">';
echo $team[0];
echo ' vs ';
echo $team[1];
echo '</a></span>';
echo '<span class="location">';
echo $location;
echo '</span>';
echo '</td>
</tr>';

}

echo '</table>';
```

This is the code I've tried but foreach loop iterates multiple time every time for loop iterates.

Comment: Your description of what you want the table to look like is very vague.  What do you mean?

Comment: show us a loop you have tried? / how are you getting the arrays? static or database

Comment: @unholyRanger Code Added

Comment: what you're trying to do and how you're doing it is still unclear.

Comment: I Want to iterate different Arrays through loops but loop within loop iterates inner loop multiple times while I wanted to run each array normally

Answer (score 0):

Might I recommend you use a class for this?  Something like the following:

```
class myClass(){
    public $title;
    public $var1;
    public $var2;
    public $var3;
    public $var4;
    public $var5;
    public $loc;

    public function __construct($title, $var1, $var2, $var3, $var4, $var5){
         $this->title = $title;
         $this->var1 = $var1;
         $this->var2 = $var2;
         $this->var3 = $var3;
         $this->var4 = $var4;
         $this->var5 = $var5;
    }

    public function printTable(){
    echo '
        <tr class="d1 vevent">
          <td>
             <b><abbr class="dtstart" title="' . $this->var1 . '">' . $this->var2 . '</abbr></b> <br>' . $this->var3 . '</td>
          <td>
              <span class="summary">' . $this->var4 . ' - ' . $this->var5 . '</span>
              <span class="location">' . $this->loc . '</span>
          </td>
        </tr>';
    }
}
```

And then you can create the objects using the data in your arrays, such as:

```
$obj = myClass($ar1_1,$ar1_2,$ar1_3, $ar1_5,$loc);
//Then print the table:
$obj->printTable();
```

Or if you had an array of objects:

```
echo "<table>";
for($objArray as $obj){
    $obj->printTable();
}
echo "</table>";
```

Lastly if you want to use your current system of arrays using this class you can do the following:

```
$longestArray = $array1;
if(count($array2)>count($longestArray)) $longestArray = $array2;
if(count($array3)>count($longestArray)) $longestArray = $array3;
if(count($array4)>count($longestArray)) $longestArray = $array4;
if(count($array5)>count($longestArray)) $longestArray = $array5;
if(count($loc)>count($longestArray)) $longestArray = $loc;

$objArray = Array();
for($i=0;$i<count($longestArray);$i++){
    $objArray[] = myClass($array1[$i],$array2[$i],$array3[$i], $array4[$i], $array5[$i], $loc[$i]);
}

echo "<table>";
for($objArray as $obj){
    $obj->printTable();
}
echo "</table>";
```

NOTE: you will get a lot of warnings about the index not existing for the array whenever the length of the array is shorter than the index, but this should be valid and execute just fine.  Also, I didn't test it so it is prone to typos.

Comment: Can u plz more elaborate it

Comment: Actually I'm poor with Arrays :(
Thanks, I will give it a try and update with the outcome here

Comment: Yeah, I've seen. Thank you. I will give it a try and will update u soon

Comment: I don't want to combine all arrays as different array to be shown at different place on table and how table tow will iterate with each of longest array items ???

Comment: The way I understand your question is you want the first element of each array to be 1 row in the table.  Then the second element of each array to be the second row in the table.  Etc.  I assume the arrays that are shorter means that the specified value for that row is undefined.  Do I have it correct?

Comment: Exactly, Thats what I need.
while shorter array doesn't mean it is undefined. It just means that it has less elements than others